# renv 0.12.0 was loaded from project library, but renv 0.11.0 is recorded in lockfile

Tags: r, ubuntu-20.04, lockfile, renv

Upon opening a project on rstudio i have the following Warning:

```
Warning message:
renv 0.12.0 was loaded from project library, but renv 0.11.0 is recorded in lockfile.
Use `renv::record("renv@0.12.0")` to record this version in the lockfile.
Use `renv::restore(packages = "renv")` to install renv 0.11.0 into the project library.
```

When running `renv::record("renv@0.12.0")` i get this message:

```
Error: no lockfile exists at path "~/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT/renv.lock"
```

And when running `renv::restore()` i get this:

```
* The library is already synchronized with the lockfile.
```

I assume there is a lockfile but it's not in that path so I looked for the lockfile on the parent directory. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04

```
find . -type f -iname 'renv.lock'
```

But there is no lockfile under this folder. What am I missing here ? Could not find any useful answer on that googling.

Update: `renv::diagnostics()` as requested

```
Diagnostics Report -- renv [0.12.0]
===================================

# Session Info =======================
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_HK.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_HK.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_HK.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_HK.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_HK.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_HK.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_HK.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gtools_3.8.2   here_0.1       adegenet_2.1.3 ade4_1.7-15   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] splines_4.0.2      shiny_1.5.0        expm_0.999-5       sp_1.4-2          
 [5] renv_0.12.0        LearnBayes_2.15.1  pillar_1.4.6       backports_1.1.9   
 [9] lattice_0.20-41    glue_1.4.2         digest_0.6.25      promises_1.1.1    
[13] colorspace_1.4-1   htmltools_0.5.0    httpuv_1.5.4       Matrix_1.2-18     
[17] plyr_1.8.6         pkgconfig_2.0.3    raster_3.3-13      gmodels_2.18.1    
[21] purrr_0.3.4        xtable_1.8-4       scales_1.1.1       gdata_2.18.0      
[25] later_1.1.0.1      tibble_3.0.3       mgcv_1.8-33        generics_0.0.2    
[29] ggplot2_3.3.2      ellipsis_0.3.1     magrittr_1.5       crayon_1.3.4      
[33] mime_0.9           deldir_0.1-29      nlme_3.1-149       MASS_7.3-53       
[37] class_7.3-17       vegan_2.5-6        tools_4.0.2        lifecycle_0.2.0   
[41] stringr_1.4.0      munsell_0.5.0      cluster_2.1.0      compiler_4.0.2    
[45] e1071_1.7-3        tinytex_0.25       rlang_0.4.7        classInt_0.4-3    
[49] units_0.6-7        grid_4.0.2         rstudioapi_0.11    igraph_1.2.5      
[53] boot_1.3-25        gtable_0.3.0       codetools_0.2-16   DBI_1.1.0         
[57] reshape2_1.4.4     R6_2.4.1           dplyr_1.0.2        fastmap_1.0.1     
[61] seqinr_3.6-1       rprojroot_1.3-2    spdep_1.1-5        KernSmooth_2.23-17
[65] permute_0.9-5      ape_5.4-1          stringi_1.5.3      parallel_4.0.2    
[69] Rcpp_1.0.5         vctrs_0.3.4        sf_0.9-6           spData_0.3.8      
[73] tidyselect_1.1.0   xfun_0.17          coda_0.19-3       

# Project ============================
Project path: "~/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT"

# Status =============================
* This project has not yet been snapshotted -- 'renv.lock' does not exist.
The following package(s) are installed but not recorded in the lockfile:
                _
  utf8            [1.1.4]
  clipr           [0.7.0]
  tidyselect      [1.1.0]
  lme4            [1.1-23]
  FactoMineR      [2.3]
  maptools        [1.0-2]
  cpp11           [0.2.1]
  sourcetools     [0.1.7]
  munsell         [0.5.0]
  units           [0.6-7]
  statmod         [1.4.34]
  withr           [2.2.0]
  colorspace      [1.4-1]
  highr           [0.8]
  knitr           [1.29]
  leaps           [3.1]
  rstudioapi      [0.11]
  ggsignif        [0.6.0]
  labeling        [0.3]
  farver          [2.0.3]
  rprojroot       [1.3-2]
  coda            [0.19-3]
  LearnBayes      [2.15.1]
  vctrs           [0.3.4]
  generics        [0.0.2]
  xfun            [0.17]
  adegenet        [2.1.3]
  R6              [2.4.1]
  markdown        [1.1]
  RcppEigen       [0.3.3.7.0]
  isoband         [0.2.2]
  RcppArmadillo   [0.9.900.3.0]
  assertthat      [0.2.1]
  promises        [1.1.1]
  scales          [1.1.1]
  nnet            [7.3-14]
  gtable          [0.3.0]
  conquer         [1.0.2]
  processx        [3.4.4]
  rlang           [0.4.7]
  MatrixModels    [0.4-1]
  scatterplot3d   [0.3-41]
  rstatix         [0.6.0]
  selectr         [0.4-2]
  broom           [0.7.0]
  yaml            [2.2.1]
  reshape2        [1.4.4]
  abind           [1.4-5]
  modelr          [0.1.8]
  backports       [1.1.9]
  httpuv          [1.5.4]
  spData          [0.3.8]
  gaston          [1.5.6]
  ggplot2         [3.3.2]
  ellipsis        [0.3.1]
  raster          [3.3-13]
  RColorBrewer    [1.1-2]
  polynom         [1.4-0]
  Rcpp            [1.0.5]
  plyr            [1.8.6]
  base64enc       [0.1-3]
  progress        [1.2.2]
  classInt        [0.4-3]
  purrr           [0.3.4]
  ps              [1.3.4]
  prettyunits     [1.1.1]
  ggpubr          [0.4.0]
  openssl         [1.4.2]
  deldir          [0.1-29]
  viridis         [0.5.1]
  cowplot         [1.1.0]
  ggrepel         [0.8.2]
  haven           [2.3.1]
  cluster         [2.1.0]
  fs              [1.5.0]
  here            [0.1]
  factoextra      [1.0.7]
  tinytex         [0.25]
  magrittr        [1.5]
  data.table      [1.13.0]
  pixmap          [0.4-11]
  openxlsx        [4.1.5]
  SparseM         [1.78]
  gmodels         [2.18.1]
  reprex          [0.3.0]
  whisker         [0.4]
  matrixStats     [0.56.0]
  pkgload         [1.1.0]
  hms             [0.5.3]
  mime            [0.9]
  evaluate        [0.14]
  xtable          [1.8-4]
  pbkrtest        [0.4-8.6]
  rio             [0.5.16]
  jpeg            [0.1-8.1]
  readxl          [1.3.1]
  gridExtra       [2.3]
  testthat        [2.3.2]
  ellipse         [0.4.2]
  tibble          [3.0.3]
  KernSmooth      [2.23-17]
  crayon          [1.3.4]
  minqa           [1.2.4]
  htmltools       [0.5.0]
  segmented       [1.2-0]
  mgcv            [1.8-33]
  later           [1.1.0.1]
  spdep           [1.1-5]
  tidyr           [1.1.2]
  expm            [0.999-5]
  RcppParallel    [5.0.2]
  lubridate       [1.7.9]
  DBI             [1.1.0]
  corrplot        [0.84]
  praise          [1.0.0]
  dbplyr          [1.4.4]
  MASS            [7.3-53]
  sf              [0.9-6]
  boot            [1.3-25]
  sys             [3.4]
  Matrix          [1.2-18]
  ade4            [1.7-15]
  car             [3.0-9]
  readr           [1.3.1]
  permute         [0.9-5]
  cli             [2.0.2]
  gdata           [2.18.0]
  igraph          [1.2.5]
  forcats         [0.5.0]
  pkgconfig       [2.0.3]
  flashClust      [1.01-2]
  foreign         [0.8-80]
  sp              [1.4-2]
  xml2            [1.3.2]
  BH              [1.72.0-3]
  rematch         [1.0.1]
  rvest           [0.3.6]
  stringr         [1.4.0]
  callr           [3.4.4]
  digest          [0.6.25]
  vegan           [2.5-6]
  rmarkdown       [2.3]
  cellranger      [1.1.0]
  dendextend      [1.14.0]
  curl            [4.3]
  shiny           [1.5.0]
  gtools          [3.8.2]
  commonmark      [1.7]
  quantreg        [5.67]
  nloptr          [1.2.2.2]
  hierfstat       [0.5-7]
  lifecycle       [0.2.0]
  nlme            [3.1-149]
  jsonlite        [1.7.1]
  carData         [3.0-4]
  seqinr          [3.6-1]
  desc            [1.2.0]
  viridisLite     [0.3.0]
  askpass         [1.1]
  fansi           [0.4.1]
  pillar          [1.4.6]
  ggsci           [2.9]
  lattice         [0.20-41]
  fastmap         [1.0.1]
  httr            [1.4.2]
  pkgbuild        [1.1.0]
  glue            [1.4.2]
  zip             [2.1.1]
  png             [0.1-7]
  class           [7.3-17]
  stringi         [1.5.3]
  blob            [1.2.1]
  latticeExtra    [0.6-29]
  renv            [0.12.0]
  dplyr           [1.0.2]
  tidyverse       [1.3.0]
  e1071           [1.7-3]
  ape             [5.4-1]

Use `renv::snapshot()` to add these packages to your lockfile.


# Packages ===========================
This project has not yet been snapshotted: 'renv.lock' does not exist.
                  Library Source Lockfile Source Path Dependency
BH               1.72.0-3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
DBI                 1.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
FactoMineR            2.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
KernSmooth        2.23-17   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
LearnBayes         2.15.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
MASS               7.3-53   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
Matrix             1.2-18   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
MatrixModels        0.4-1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
R6                  2.4.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
RColorBrewer        1.1-2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
Rcpp                1.0.5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
RcppArmadillo 0.9.900.3.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
RcppEigen       0.3.3.7.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
RcppParallel        5.0.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
SparseM              1.78   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
abind               1.4-5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ade4               1.7-15   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
adegenet            2.1.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
ape                 5.4-1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
askpass               1.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
assertthat          0.2.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
backports           1.1.9   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
base64enc           0.1-3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
blob                1.2.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
boot               1.3-25   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
broom               0.7.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
callr               3.4.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
car                 3.0-9   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
carData             3.0-4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
cellranger          1.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
class              7.3-17   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
classInt            0.4-3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
cli                 2.0.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
clipr               0.7.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
cluster             2.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
coda               0.19-3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
codetools          0.2-16   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
colorspace          1.4-1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
commonmark            1.7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
compiler             <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
conquer             1.0.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
corrplot             0.84   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
cowplot             1.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
cpp11               0.2.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
crayon              1.3.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
curl                  4.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
data.table         1.13.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
datasets             <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
dbplyr              1.4.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
deldir             0.1-29   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
dendextend         1.14.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
desc                1.2.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
digest             0.6.25   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
dplyr               1.0.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
e1071               1.7-3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ellipse             0.4.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ellipsis            0.3.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
evaluate             0.14   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
expm              0.999-5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
factoextra          1.0.7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
fansi               0.4.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
farver              2.0.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
fastmap             1.0.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
flashClust         1.01-2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
forcats             0.5.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
foreign            0.8-80   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
fs                  1.5.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
gaston              1.5.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
gdata              2.18.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
generics            0.0.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ggplot2             3.3.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
ggpubr              0.4.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ggrepel             0.8.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ggsci                 2.9   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ggsignif            0.6.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
glue                1.4.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
gmodels            2.18.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
grDevices            <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
graphics             <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
grid                 <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
gridExtra             2.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
gtable              0.3.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
gtools              3.8.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
haven               2.3.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
here                  0.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
hierfstat           0.5-7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
highr                 0.8   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
hms                 0.5.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
htmltools           0.5.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
httpuv              1.5.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
httr                1.4.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
igraph              1.2.5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
isoband             0.2.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
jpeg              0.1-8.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
jsonlite            1.7.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
knitr                1.29   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
labeling              0.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
later             1.1.0.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
lattice           0.20-41   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]     direct
latticeExtra       0.6-29   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]     direct
leaps                 3.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
lifecycle           0.2.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
lme4               1.1-23   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
lubridate           1.7.9   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
magrittr              1.5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
maptools            1.0-2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
markdown              1.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
matrixStats        0.56.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
methods              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
mgcv               1.8-33   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
mime                  0.9   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
minqa               1.2.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
modelr              0.1.8   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
munsell             0.5.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
nlme              3.1-149   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
nloptr            1.2.2.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
nnet               7.3-14   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
openssl             1.4.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
openxlsx            4.1.5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
parallel             <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
pbkrtest          0.4-8.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
permute             0.9-5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
pillar              1.4.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
pixmap             0.4-11   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
pkgbuild            1.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
pkgconfig           2.0.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
pkgload             1.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
plyr                1.8.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
png                 0.1-7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
polynom             1.4-0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
praise              1.0.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
prettyunits         1.1.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
processx            3.4.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
progress            1.2.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
promises            1.1.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
ps                  1.3.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
purrr               0.3.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
quantreg             5.67   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
raster             3.3-13   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
readr               1.3.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
readxl              1.3.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rematch             1.0.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
renv               0.12.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
reprex              0.3.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
reshape2            1.4.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rio                0.5.16   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rlang               0.4.7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rmarkdown             2.3   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rpart              4.1-15   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
rprojroot           1.3-2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rstatix             0.6.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rstudioapi           0.11   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
rvest               0.3.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
scales              1.1.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
scatterplot3d      0.3-41   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
segmented           1.2-0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
selectr             0.4-2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
seqinr              3.6-1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
sf                  0.9-6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
shiny               1.5.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
sourcetools         0.1.7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
sp                  1.4-2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
spData              0.3.8   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
spatial            7.3-12   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
spdep               1.1-5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]   indirect
splines              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 27 rows ]

[1]: /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[2]: /tmp/RtmpdZmmFV/renv-system-library                                      

# User Profile =======================
[no user profile detected]

# Settings ===========================
List of 6
 $ external.libraries       : chr(0) 
 $ ignored.packages         : chr(0) 
 $ package.dependency.fields: chr [1:3] "Imports" "Depends" "LinkingTo"
 $ snapshot.type            : chr "implicit"
 $ use.cache                : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.library       : logi TRUE

# Options ============================
List of 2
 $ renv.consent: logi TRUE
 $ renv.verbose: logi TRUE

# Environment Variables ==============
HOME                        = /home/alex
LANG                        = en_HK.UTF-8
R_LIBS                      = <NA>
R_LIBS_SITE                 = /usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library
R_LIBS_USER                 = /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu:/tmp/RtmpdZmmFV/renv-system-library
RENV_DEFAULT_R_ENVIRON      = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_ENVIRON_USER = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS         = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS_SITE    = /usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS_USER    = ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
RENV_DEFAULT_R_PROFILE      = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_PROFILE_USER = <NA>
RENV_PROJECT                = /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT

# PATH ===============================
- /usr/local/sbin
- /usr/local/bin
- /usr/sbin
- /usr/bin
- /sbin
- /bin
- /usr/games
- /usr/local/games
- /snap/bin
- /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/postback

# Cache ==============================
There are a total of 166 package(s) installed in the renv cache.
Cache path: "~/.local/share/renv/cache/v5/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
```

Again the lockfile seems to not exist

Comment: What is the output of `renv::project()`? `renv::diagnostics()` might also be useful.

Comment: `renv::project()` is `/home/alex/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT` and `renv::diagnostics()` i will edit the question because it's big here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is ultimately a small bug in `renv`. Here's my guess at what's happening:

1. While this project has been initialized as an `renv` project, it does not have a lockfile for some reason. (Perhaps `renv::activate()` was called to initialize `renv` without explicitly creating a lockfile?)
2. The project has an `renv` autoloader; this is from a script at `renv/activate.R`. That script is configured to load `renv 0.11.0`.
3. When the project is loaded, `renv` finds that `renv 0.12.0` is installed in the project library, not the expected version `0.11.0`. This causes the warning to be emitted. (Perhaps `renv` was updated in that project previously?)

So, ultimately, the warning is misleading here -- the request for `renv 0.11.0` comes directly from the autoloader, not from the lockfile (which does not exist). As for *why* the lockfile does not exist, I'm not sure -- but it most likely implies the project was initialized via `renv::activate()`, and not by `renv::init()`.

All that said -- you can safely re-generate the lockfile via `renv::snapshot()`.

Comment: thanks. I do not remember whether `renv::activate()` was called since i created `renv` on the GUI of Rstudio when creating a project. The script `renv/activate.R` is indeed present  and it starts as you predicted `local({

  # the requested version of renv
  version <- "0.11.0"` . Shall I change the script to `0.12.0` ? will this silence the Warning ?

Comment: ok done the warning was silenced. Could you explain me some things ? Is it important to have a lockfile ? What is a lockfile used for ?  Thanks a lot

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation at https://rstudio.github.io/renv/, and then following up at https://community.rstudio.com/ if you have more questions.